# WPF WebBrowser Document Completed event

Tags: wpf, browser

I want to know if there is an event that is fired when a document is fully loaded in a WebBrowser Control  in WPF.

Thanks in advance,
Paulo

Comment: Learn how to use the official documentation please, besides that you can just use F12 on a WebBrowser to go to its definition where all properties, methods and events are listed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted.aspx)